# Backward algorithm evaluation for HMM

Tags: algorithm, models, hidden-markov-models

I am having confusion on theoretical description and implementation of Baum Welch:

- The description of forward and backward algorithms in most documents gives a notion of an intermediate symbol where Forward and backward algorithms intersect
  i.e. Forward algorithm will evaluate it till "t" and backward will do it from "t+1".
- But the examples indicate that the forward algorithm evaluates from X1 till X(T) and Backward algorithm does the same job of forward algorithm but it evaluates from end i.e. from X(T) till X(1).
- But why the theoretical descriptions gives a notion of an intermediate symbol where evaluation is stopped for both forward and backward algorithms?

Can I get some clarification on this?

Comment: The goal of introducing `t` in forward and backward algorithms is to compute the corresponding probability in O(S^2 T) time using dynamic programming. A straightforward computation of these probabilities requires enumerating all state sequences of length T and is thus exponential.

Comment: Thanks Sergei for the answer. I do have another question in relation to this. I understand the initial conditions of forward probability which comes from initial guess. But, how to interpret the initial condition for backward probability (which is "1" for all states at time = N)

Comment: Recall that backward probability `\beta_t(i)` is a probability of seeing all observations `X_t, ..., X_T` **given** that the `t`-th state is `i`. This definition implies that `\beta_T(i)` is not random:

* the randomness of observations `X_1, ..., X_T` was accounted for in `\beta_t(i)` where `t < T`;
* state at time `T` is not random as well, because `\beta` is conditioned on the state being `i`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sergei. This helps. Any document link which you can provide where this is described in detail?